# Is it possible to display DONE keywords in org-todo-list?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

The documentation for `org-todo-list` states:

> Show all (not done) TODO entries from all agenda file in a single list.

By default, the function shows ALL items with a TODO keyword. Is it possible to show items with a DONE keyword as well?

I know it's possible to use `'N r'` to select individual keywords to show, but I have multiple TODO and multiple DONE states and would like to view them all simultaneously.

A huge bonus would be the ability to show ALL TODO and all DONE keywords individually as well.

For reference, my keywords are:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
   '(;; Sequence for TASKS
     (sequence "TODO(t@/!)" "WAITING(w@/!)" "DELEGATED(e@/!)" "|" "ASSIGNED(.@/!)" "CANCELLED(x@/!)" "DONE(d@/!)")

     ;; Sequence for POSSESSIONS
     (sequence "PURCHASE(p@/!)" "PURCHASED(j@/!)" "TRANSIT(u@/!)" "GIFT(h@/!)" "SELL(k@/!)" "LOANED(n@/!)" "|" "UNWANTED(a@/!)" "OWN(o@/!)" "GIFTED(g@/!)"  "SOLD(c@/!)" "DISCARDED(q@/!)")

     ;; Sequence for MULTIMEDIA
     (sequence "CONSUME(r@/!)" "SUBSCRIBE(b@/!)" "CONSUMING(l@/!)" "SHARE(s@/!)" "|" "IGNORED(i@/!)" "REFERENCE(f@/!)")

     ;; Sequence for EVENTS
     (sequence "VISIT(v@/!)" "|" "DIDNOTGO(z@/!)" "MEETING(m@/!)" "VISITED(y@/!)")))
```

Comment: Without getting into the functionality of `org-todo-list`, it is possible to restrict a search to a user specified criteria using `org-agenda-list`, `org-search-view` and/or `org-tags-view`.  Many users have not yet mastered the advanced searching techniques discussed in the manual:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html .  And, it is possible, to have several different searches with all results appearing in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer with the different views blocked in sections.  My first inclination, without researching `org-todo-list`, is to create your own search.

Comment: If you have not already discovered the write-ups by Sacha Chua, you may be interested in taking a look at her org-mode and org-agenda-mode configuration for pre-configured searches:  http://pages.sachachua.com/.emacs.d/Sacha.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression matching to match any non-empty `TODO` state.  Use the tags view (`C-c a m`) and search for `TODO={.+}`.  You can save this in `org-agenda-custom-commands` if you use it frequently.  You can also search for individual keywords: `TODO="TODO"`, `TODO="ASSIGNED"` and so on.